# How do I use document.querySelector to select a particular output of text from a node using document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I use document.querySelectorAll() to select a particular output of text from the code below?

I'd like to capture the result in a variable and am attempting to do so with the following code:

```
let result = document.querySelectorAll('.coinmarketcap-currency-widget');
```

The `querySelectorAll()` returns a node list. My question is how do I get to the particular child node that I need?

I need to select the text from a span tag element with the value of "0.044763 USD". My question is how do I get to the particular child node that I need (0.044763 USD)?

```
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget">
<div style="border:2px">
<div><div style="float:right;width:67%;">

<span style="font-size: 18px;"><a href="http://coinmarketcap.com/" target="_blank">TRON (TRX)</a></span> <br>            
<span style="font-size: 16px;">

    0.044763 USD 

    <span style="color:#d14836">(-3.85%)</span></span>
```

Comment: You'd need to have some way of identifying it. In the above, for instance, it's 1. The second `span` in its parent, 2. The first span after a span with an `a` in it, 3. The only span containing "USD"...

Comment: wouldnt be better to assign an id or class to the span you'll need and query directly that element?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a list of nodes matching the given selector. If you need a specific child element, you need to improve your selector code, such as `.coinmarketcap-currency-widget span[style="font-size: 16px;"]`, or whatever fits your goal.

Comment: If you want you can easily convert the node list to an array and use find with an appropriate predicate function, e.g. `[].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("div")).find( function(el) { return false; } );` -- return `true` or something truthy on a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following as a simple solution and saving it to a variable.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this selecor `.coinmarketcap-currency-widget div > span:last-child` to get the target span and split the innerHTML to get the value

```js
let result = document.querySelectorAll('.coinmarketcap-currency-widget div > span:last-child');
console.log(result[0].innerHTML.split("<span")[0]);
```

```html
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget">
  <div style="border:2px">
    <div>

      <div style="float:right;width:67%;">

        <span style="font-size: 18px;">
            <a href="http://coinmarketcap.com/" target="_blank">TRON (TRX)</a>
        </span> 
<br>
        <span style="font-size: 16px;">

    0.044763 USD 

           <span style="color:#d14836">(-3.85%)</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the OP, it's good to remember the result of `document.querySelectorAll` is an array-like object. Even if there is only one result, it's still going to be in a collection.

Comment: don't use innerhtml if you just want the text node contents.

Comment: @the8472 what if the node has a mixed content (text + another node)?